# item to hide once overdue by 1 day

Tags: php, calendar, hide

Ok, I am fairly new to the PHP scene so please correct anything I might have done wrong ect. I am trying to do a calender list, which as soon as it get to the day after the due date it hides it from view. I currently have it getting the information that is submitted however not sure how to continue from here to make the overdue items hide? I have attached my code below for feedback also.

```
<?php
include 'db-connect.php'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tasks");

echo "<table border='0' align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Task Title:</th>
<th>Task Description:</th>
<th>Due Date:</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['task'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['datedue'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your MYSQL query

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE datedue >= CURDATE()
```

This would only return the rows that were higher or equal to the current date.

Comment: Brill, :D thanks for that did not work at first until i noticed you had the > sign the wrong way! thanks pal really appreciated

Comment: Whups! Brain is dead today. Fixed.